App Scripts - moving slide based on change in gsheet
Using the google products and working with app scripts to get some more automations going, but this one is frying my brain :/
In a gsheet we track the program status and in a slide deck, we have one slide linked per program.
Sheetname "Programs":
Column C: Program Status ("Active", "Full" or "Closed")
Column G: Link to program specific slide
What I want to do:
If the Program Status in C is changed to "Full" or "Closed", the program slide in G should be moved to the end of the presentation.
If the Program Status in C is changed to "Active", the program slide in G should be moved to the front (position 2) of the presentation.
Example:
Current situation -> C2 = Active and Slide in G2 is on position 5
C2 is manually changed to "Closed" -> Slide in G2 is automatically moved to position 200 (some very high number)
C2 is manually changed to "Active" -> Slide in G2 is automatically moved to position 2
Could someone please help me?
I know how to check for a value and how to move a slide, but not how to connect them together :(
